# How to show specific post meta?

Tags: theme-development, post-meta

I have a post name player_list.This page has some post meta data.I want to show one of them in another page.I want to show player number.This metabox id is `$pb_squad_number`.

In another page. I have a metabox where I am selecting some players from the player_list post.Now I want to show the selected players number I assigned in that metabox of player_list post.I used following code but shows nothing.Post thuimbnail  and title are working fine.

```
<?php 

          $home_starting_player_names = rwmb_meta( 'pb_home_starting_player_options', array( 'multiple' => true ) ); ?>
          <?php 
           foreach ( $home_starting_player_names as $home_starting_player ){?>
            <li role="presentation">
            <aside class="starting-player-image"><?php  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($home_starting_player); ?></aside>
            <aside class="starting-player-number"><?php  echo get_the_title($home_starting_player); ?></aside>
           <aside class="starting-player-name"><?php  echo get_post_meta($home_starting_player, $pb_squad_number); ?></aside>
           </li>
       <?php } 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo get_post_meta($home_starting_player, $pb_squad_number, true);
```

The code you have returns an array; the third parameter specifies a single value.

Comment: Hi - if this worked for you then please consider accepting the answer.